# Loading NSTableView Lazily

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

On iOS, an NSTableView (UITableView) is loaded lazily, in the sense that the table only displays the cell that are needed for the current view and not more. As the user scrolls up or down, more information is loaded from the data source.

Is there something similar for OSX? I have an NSTableView with 1000+ records to load (+multiple columns) which is resulting in laggy loading as well as lag when scrolling up or down.

Would this 'lazy' loading be a good solution(if possible)? Or maybe something along the same lines?

Thanks.

P.S. Regarding the loading process - I use the two usual methods

```
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

and

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
```

to load the data. Within them there are if statements to check some variables, since I have 2 combo boxes that contain data, that when containing "ALL" and "ALL" load these 1000+ records. If the combo boxes are not "ALL" and "ALL", then only a couple of records are loaded, which load just fine.

I think the problem, given that you have explained that lazy loading is done automatically, is that I am loading the data from XML files, so maybe the parsing is taking up a large chunk of processing time.

I though of loading the data from the XML file into an NSDictionary at runtime and keeping it in memory, available for use when needed, so that I can avoid the loading time when the information is actually needed to display.

What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: `NSTableView` content is indeed loaded lazily.  Are you providing the data through a data source, or through bindings?  If through a data source, please post your implementation of `objectValueForTableColumn: row:`.  If through bindings, look at the accessors, and see if any of them do processing more complicated than returning an existing ivar.

Comment: @Dondragmer is exactly right. The only reason that `NSTableView` will not load lazily is if you've done something wrong. We need more information about how you're populating the table view.

Comment: Thanks guys! I have added a P.S. with further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to cache your XML file into some sort of data structure.  The `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` method will be called *once for every visible cell*.  If you have a lot of columns, it's easy to have 200 cells visible.  Page down, and those cells all change, your XML file loads 200 times, and you get laggy scrolling.

Even if the XML file is only loaded and parsed for every cell in a specific column, it will be slow and should be fixed.

You can verify that the caching is necessary by making `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` return `nil` where it would otherwise parse the XML file.  Once you make this change, does it scroll smoothly, or do you have other problems?  It would obviously make the application unusable, but you should always check if an optimization is necessary and sufficient before implementing it.

Comment: Can you expand on "making cells return nil" ?

Comment: I've re-worded my answer.  The question about scrolling is only meaningful after you make this change.